# jsf ajax call: executing javascript function in the end

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

I'm working with JSF 2.0 and here's my form:

```
<h:form id="fff" onsubmit="reloadMap();">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{rentCarPoolBean.state}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{rentCarPoolBean.stateList}" id="stateList" />
        <f:ajax event="change" render="cities stateSelected" onevent="showAlert"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu  id="cities" value="#{rentCarPoolBean.city}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{rentCarPoolBean.cityList}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:outputText value="#{rentCarPoolBean.state}" id="stateSelected" />
</h:form>
```

And the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAlert(data){
         if (data.status == "complete")
             alert(document.getElementById("stateSelected"));   
    }
</script>
```

What the above code does is on selecting a state from the first dropdown, it makes the ajax call and renders the 'cities' dropdown and the 'stateSelected' outputText.
Also, it calls the showAlert() javascript function.
What I want to do is call the javascript function after all the data is returned and both the dropdown and the outputText have been rendered.
But currently the javascript function is called before the elements are rendered and the alert displays `null`.
How do we make the javascript function execute in the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to hook on a status of `success` instead. This will run after the HTML DOM tree has been updated. The status of `complete` runs directly after the ajax response has been returned. This is admittedly a misleading status name, but you should try to interpret it in context of "HTTP request" like as the `begin` status.

Another problem is that the `document.getElementById()` selects items by the HTML element ID, not by JSF component ID. You need to give it exactly the ID as JSF has generated to the HTML. You can figure the right HTML element ID by viewing the page source in webbrowser.

All with all, your new function should look like this:

```
function showAlert(data){
     if (data.status == "success")
         alert(document.getElementById("fff:stateSelected"));  
}
```

Comment: have tried both `complete` and `success`. Both give the same result.

Comment: I checked your code once again. Where is the component identified by `timeResult`? Is it inside the same form or not?

Comment: document.getElementById("fff:stateSelected") returns `null` because the id generated is `j_idt6:fff`. How do we get this id in the javascript function?

Comment: You need to look for the HTML element with `id="j_idt6"` in the generated HTML source code and then trackback the responsible JSF component for this in the JSF source code and then give it a fixed JSF component ID. The HTML element ID will then also become fixed with this value. JSF components which prepends the client IDs are all `UINamingContainer` components like `<h:form>`, `<f:subview>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<ui:repeat>`, etc. If yours turns out to be another `<h:form>`, then you've another problem: nesting forms is illegal.

Comment: I added the `prependId="false"` attribute on the form objects. Now the element id's are plain id's that I set while defining them :)

Comment: This is not generally recommended. What was the component with `id="j_idt6"`? Was it another `<h:form>`? Nesting forms is illegal in HTML. The browser behaviour is unspecified.

Comment: Yes it was another <h:form> and I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
alert(document.getElementById("stateSelected"));
```

you're specifying only JSF component id, but you need to give a full clientId. Here's a [link](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html) explaining this.